# When using DropDownListFor how do I bind the SelectList to the Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This page works in two steps,

Step 1 - The user hits Index() and the SelectList is populated with the applications from the databse.

Step 2 - they select an applicaiton from the list, which posts the page back, which reloads the page with the application Details added

Error: When I run this and get to step 2, I get an error back saying: 
**The ViewData item that has the key 'ApplicationId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.**

This appears to be because the Model.ApplicationList is now null as it hasn't bound back to the model when the form was posted, can I make it do this?

**View:**

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ApplicationId, Model.ApplicationList, "Select an Application" ,  new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
}
```

**Model:**

```cs
public class IndexModel
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ApplicationList { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set}
}
```

**Controller:**

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var dc = new Entities())
    {
        var model = new IndexModel();

        model.ApplicationList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var applications = dc.Applications.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();

        foreach (var application in applications)
        {
            model.ApplicationList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = false,
                Text = application.Name,
                Value = application.Id.ToString()
            });
        }

        model.ApplicationId = 1;

        return View(model);
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexModel model)
{   
    model.Detail = GetDetail(model.ApplicationId);
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem. It doesn't look like .net mvc3 lets you do this without the help of jquery. Drop down lists will get their selected item bound to the model when posting but not all the items in the combo box. You would have to rebuild it each time you pass the viewmodel back to the view.

Another way around losing the dropdown list is to use ajax.